# Horizontal scrolling tweets

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, tweets

I am trying to integrate a scrolling tweet bar at the top of my site and so far, I have followed several tutorials that all seem to follow the same material, but I can't get it to work.

What happens is the facility shows up but just says "Loading" I think I have all the code set right, but I might be missing something, could someone offer a nudge in the right direction please? :)

here is the header code for the feed:

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='js/jquery.marquee.js'></script> 
  <script type='text/javascript'>
      //<![CDATA[ 
   var Twitter = {
    init: function () {
     // Pass in the username you want to display feeds for
   this.insertLatestTweets('GumBumRadio');
    }, 

    // This replaces the <p>Loading...</p> with the tweets
    insertLatestTweets: function (username) {
     var limit = 5; // How many feeds do you want?
     var url  = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=GumBumRadio' + username + '&count=' + limit + '&callback=?';

     // Now ajax in the feeds from twitter.com
     $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
      // We'll start by creating a normal marquee-element for the tweets
      var html = '<marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="1" direction="left">';

      // Loop through all the tweets and create a link for each
      for (var i in data) {
       html += '<a href="http://twitter.com/' + username + '#status_' + data[i].id_str + '">' + data[i].text + ' <i>' + Twitter.daysAgo(data[i].created_at) + '</i></a>';
      }

      html += '</marquee>';

      // Now replace the <p> with our <marquee>-element
      $('#twitter p').replaceWith(html);

      // The marquee element looks quite shite so we'll use Remy Sharp's plug-in to replace it with a smooth one
      Twitter.fancyMarquee();
     });
    }, 

    // Replaces the marquee-element with a fancy one
    fancyMarquee: function () {
     // Replace the marquee and do some fancy stuff (taken from remy sharp's website)
     $('#twitter marquee').marquee('pointer')
      .mouseover(function () {
       $(this).trigger('stop');
      })
      .mouseout(function () {
       $(this).trigger('start');
      })
      .mousemove(function (event) {
       if ($(this).data('drag') == true) {
        this.scrollLeft = $(this).data('scrollX') + ($(this).data('x') - event.clientX);
       }
      })
      .mousedown(function (event) {
       $(this).data('drag', true).data('x', event.clientX).data('scrollX', this.scrollLeft);
      })
      .mouseup(function () {
       $(this).data('drag', false);
      });
    }, 

    // Takes a date and return the number of days it's been since said date
    daysAgo: function (date) {
     // TODO: Fix date for IE...
     if ($.browser.msie) {
      return '1 day ago';
     }

     var d = new Date(date).getTime();
     var n = new Date().getTime();

     var numDays = Math.round(Math.abs(n - d) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
     var daysAgo = numDays + ' days ago';

     if (numDays == 0) {
      daysAgo = 'today';
     }
     else if (numDays == 2) {
      daysAgo = numDays + ' day ago';
     }

     return daysAgo;
    }
   };

   Twitter.init();
   //]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: Have a look in your browsers console window for any specific error messages.

Comment: nope, no errors, here is the link, you can see how its just not doing anything.http://www.bella-web.co.uk/GumBumRadio/GumBumRadio2013/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be something wrong with the generated twitter link. In my browser it's requesting:

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=?GumBumRadio&count=5&callback=jQuery16106500070334877819_1351522993556&_=1351522993562

which returns

```
jquery16106500070334877819_1351522993556({"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]});
```

EDIT:

It's the ? mark in the screen_name variable. Also you're including the username `GumBumRadio` in a variable which it also hardcoded in the URL link.

Comment: thats strange, ive just checked the url and it pulls back my Twitter Account - im using Chrome.http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=GumBumRadio

Comment: In your browser monitor what network connections are being made. You'll see the issue then. Just press F12 in Chrome/IE to bring up the dev tools and look under "Network". Then refresh your page

Comment: ok, will take a look, ive changed the url link to the one that hits the Twitter account, but still no luck, I will give F12 a check now. :)

Comment: right, found the issue, will check this out many thanks Dave, appreciate the help. :)

Comment: fixed, it thanks for the f12 heads up- got it sorted now! Brilliant.

Comment: Just for anyone using this particular solution the v1 API has been retired meaning the above solution will no longer work. You will need to adapt this to the v1.1 REST API now and pass the relevant authentication details across even for accessing a public timeline which is ridiculous I know.